# What, as far as can be determined if the original dev is unavailable, is involved in updating the haxe externs for PhaserJS?

Tags: haxe, phaser-framework

Phaser is a javascript game engine/framework/library.
https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser

haxe-phaser is, as you would expect, a set of externs for Phaser.
https://github.com/Blank101/haxe-phaser

js2hx is designed to create externs for Phaser specifically, it says "for Phaser, some assembly required" on the tin right.
https://github.com/Blank101/js2hx

The current version of Phaser is 2.6.1 as of this writing, and the most recent externs for Phaser are for version 2.4.6. There have been some significant improvements to Phaser in that time, including the very recent addition of multi texture support allowing for multiple atlases to be loaded at once, that I would really like to keep if at all possible.

I have been using Phaser for 8~ months, javascript for the same period (I learned it for Phaser specifically) and really love the engine. I initially learned it because I had a terrible time breaking into the haxe scene and actually went from haxeflixel, flixel and then found Phaser, and have been very pleased with it ever since. Why switch now? I'm optimistically hoping to move towards native mobile for iOS and Android, along with native desktop clients and Phaser doesn't really do that. It hurts me to be looking at switching, but that's life.

I'm thinking haxe to javascript for Phaser projects will ease me into a working knowledge of the haxe toolkit, whereas learning haxeflixel/flambe/etc. would be starting from scratch. Is that essentially correct?

What needs to be done here to update the externs, and is it likely I'll be able to do it with some persistence, or is it probably beyond me?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is contact the author directly to ask how to update. There is also a similar issue open on Github https://github.com/Blank101/haxe-phaser/issues/57

Answer (score 0):

> Why switch now? I'm optimistically hoping to move towards native mobile for iOS and Android, along with native desktop clients and Phaser doesn't really do that. It hurts me to be looking at switching, but that's life.

Have you done any research into Cordova, Ionic, PhoneGap, Electron, etc? These programs allow you to turn any HTML5/JS project into a desktop & mobile app. I've never used Haxe, but abandoning PhaserJS to make a mobile app is not necessary.

Personally I made an [Android game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jtronlabs.birdu) with Cordova, and am currently [updating it](https://github.com/JTronLabs/Birdu) to the new Phaser engine, ES6, for performance improvements, etc. Will post a blog about it when finished.

Anyways, like I said I don't know much about Haxe. However, if the original contributor of a Open Source repo is not available, you can always fork that repo and just use the copy that you update.

Comment: Ludei/Cocoon is the only option, that I'm aware of, that supports full hardware acceleration, and I had enough issues making sure things translated from web to mobile on the last project I used it for that I opted not to bother the next time around. Such has been my experience, but maybe I missed something important.

Comment: I guess it depends on what markets you want to go into. Hadn't heard that about Ludei/Cocoon, will check it out. Thanks!